# Formfill in Javascript not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var tagMatch;
    if (tagMatch = window.location.href.match(/\/questions\/ask\?tags=([^&]+)/)) {
       $(function() { 
         if (!$('#tagnames').val().length) {
         $('#tagnames').val(unescape(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
          }
     });
     }
```

Hi all, this JS code is supposed to match the latter-part of a URL of the form `/questions/ask?tags=some-tag`, and then plug the text contained in the part of the URL after `tags=` into a textbox with the id `#tagnames`. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

**I'm still learning so if you would want to show me how to fix my regex or anything else, please do!**

Comment: Why are you placing the document ready event inside the statement?

Comment: I'm still learning, where would you put it?

Comment: see my answer - I still think you've just got the variable names wrong `tagMatch` vs `match`.

Comment: Can you identify what is being stored in tagMatch in the if statement?

Comment: no. How would I do that?

Comment: Actually yes, it will store anything that gets entered there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error is with this line

```
if (!$('#tagnames').val().length)
```

length will return a number and check that against number.

Something like

```
if ($('#tagnames').val().length > 0)
```

I don't think there is a need to place document ready inside the if statement. Isn't this better.

```
 $(function() { 
       var tagMatch;
       if (tagMatch = window.location.href.match(/\/questions\/ask\?tags=([^&]+)/)) 
       {
           if ($('#tagnames').val().length > 0)
           {
               $('#tagnames').val(unescape(match[1].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
           }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Yea, if #tagnames is valid, `$('#tagnames').val().length` always return >= 0 but I'm not sure this is the ONLY problem here.

Comment: Hey Alex, not meaning to be picky, but if it was the tagMatch vs match variable name... shouldn't mine be the "correct" answer? :)

Comment: Yes, and I thank you for that, but rahul put more effort into his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without looking too much into how the string matching works...

You seem to be defining and setting a variable called `tagMatch`, but then you're using a variable called `match` to set the value.

Is that the problem?

**Update:** Apologies - your regex is correct - I misread the intention :)

Comment: Does it work if you have a second querystring variable? Without one?